# Where do I save a python file I want to call in Julia?

Tags: python, julia

I have a python script which computes an array, and I would like to use this array in Julia.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can you create a pickle file of an array from Python and have it read by Julia?

Comment: Use a standard data transmission format like JSON

Comment: @AnnZen https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @rdas Thanks, but I've read that article before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a long and complicated python script, and you want to call it directly from Julia and have the resulting array returned directly to Julia, the easiest option is probably to wrap your Python script into a Python module, install that module anywhere on your Python path, and import it into Julia with [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl), using something along the lines of:

```
using PyCall
my_python_package = pyimport("my_python_package")
foo = my_python_package.my_python_function(some_arguments)
```

If your script is *not* so long and complicated, then it may be faster to just call the underlying Python modules directly from Julia, e.g.:

```
julia> using PyCall
julia> np = pyimport("numpy")
PyObject <module 'numpy' from '/Users/.../python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>

julia> np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
1000-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -0.05105327176117878
  0.5173117443548936
  1.2998060543454042
  ⋮
 -0.022888531778737377
 -0.6389562444313613
  0.6727725474307601
```

Note also that you can specify which Python PyCall uses with

```
julia> ENV["PYTHON"] = "/path/to/my/python/executable"
julia> Pkg.build("PyCall")
```

and can run arbitrary snippets of Python code from Julia with

```
julia> pyeval("1+1") # 1+1, but in python
2
julia> py"1+1" # this does the same thing
2
julia> py"""
   some longer python snippet including characters
   like newlines or \
   that I don't want to have to have to escape
   """ # also an option
```

Comment: Thanks alot that was quite helpful.